# How can I intercept GTK main loop, or have a callback event for the main function using python gtk?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I have a basic program working that displays a slider.  I understand the concept of them using callbacks based on events.  What I want to do is say update an image, or update the log automatically without having a user interact, so it would basically be calling this event all the time.  I'm not sure if there is a callback for it or not but any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm understanding you right, you can use [`gobject.timeout_add`](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/gobject-functions.html#function-gobject--timeout-add) to do this.

Comment: I've used this for DBus programming, and timeout_add() is exactly what you want to use.

Comment: Awesome, worked like a charm, thank you, exactly what I wanted.

**NOTE: Anyone reading this as a solution, make sure your function returns True or False, it runs forever if you return True, False if you don't.

The code can be found: https://github.com/ingenuitas/SimpleCV/blob/master/SimpleCV/examples/display/gtk-example-camera.py

Answer (score 3):

This looks like polling, which is bad, as it's ressource consuming. In fact you should still use events, as the event that should trigger the update should be fired when your image has changed.

If you want to execute stuff in the background however, maybe what you want is an idle event handler, which is run each time the program has no more event to process. Use [`g_idle_add`](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-idle-add) for that.

If what you want is to perform an action, say, every 5 seconds, then used a timer event instead, as Jeremy proposed. You should use [`g_timeout_add_seconds`](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add-seconds) for a time multiple of a second (it avoids waking up the CPU for no reason, which is useful for good power management), or [`g_timeout_add`](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add) for milliseconds granularity.